# How can i update if MYSQL [BLOB] is NULL

Tags: php, mysql

How can i update if Image field in MYSQL is empty or no image is uploaded?

I tried this but doesnt update anything.

```
     UPDATE `db`.`ts126` SET `Image` = LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\user\Desktop\aa\bb\cc\placeholder.png') WHERE Image=""
```

Also i tried

```
    UPDATE `db`.`ts126`
   SET `Image` = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\aa\bb\cc\placeholder.png'
 WHERE Image="" OR Image IS NULL
```

Which is without LOAD_FILE in this case it updates the images `[BLOB - 64 B]` but When i display the image using PHP code Nothing shows up

Comment: subject says "null". you can **NOT** test for null with `=`. try `where image is null` instead

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE `db`.`ts126`
  SET `Image` = LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\user\Desktop\aa\bb\cc\placeholder.png')
WHERE Image="" OR Image IS NULL
```

Comment: Can i Update image field without LOAD_FILE something is wrong with this command and my database i tired using it several time but no luck

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? What is the size of the file? Can you add `SHOW CREATE TABLE db.ts126` and the result of `SELECT @@max_allowed_bytes`?

Comment: the Size of the file is `27Kb` and Limit is `(Max: 131 kKiB)` where do i add that code next to update command?

Comment: I tried update all without Load_File and from PHP doesn't show the image and on mysql it shown me `[BLOB - 64 B]`

Comment: Sorry I'm not too clear on your problem. Can you update the question with the code you're running and the output?

Comment: i added some if that helps

Comment: If you want to store the path, you'd need to use the `file_get_contents`  function in PHP to retrieve the actual image. In such a case, change your column to a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I used this to display image in php and works Fine `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image']).'" />` but i am not able to upload files to that

Comment: Then `LOAD_FILE` isn't your problem, what do you mean you can't upload files to it? Sounds like a new question

Comment: Sorry I mean update, it doesn't update when using `LOAD_FILE` sometimes i get 11 rows affected and still image field show `[BLOB 0]` when i try the same statement i  get 0 row affected.

Comment: here is my statment looks like] `UPDATE `db`.`ts126` SET `Tire_Image` = LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\User\aa\bb\cc\brand\TM900.png') WHERE Brand_Name="TM900HP"`